# Replace srcset sizes onclick with jquery

Tags: jquery, srcset

On an `img` tag that's using `srcset` I'm trying to enable a 50% width image become 100% when clicked. The 100% width is achieved with `togggleClass` but I need the `sizes` content of `srcset` to be changed as well. I'm hoping this will ensure performance is retained along with appropriate image src sizes.

ie: When clicked, an image changes from `sizes="(min-width: 29em) 50vw, 100vw"` to `sizes="100vw"`

```
<div class="photo-set col-1-1 bp2-col-1-2">
    <img src="..." srcset="..."
      sizes="(min-width: 29em) 50vw, 100vw">
</div>

<script>
  $(".photo-set").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('full-width');
  });
</script>
<style>
  .bp2-col-1-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .full-width {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find()` with parameter selector string `"img"` chained to `.toggleClass()`, `.attr("sizes", /* value */)` to set the `sizes` attribute of `img` element within `.photo-set` element.

```js
  $(".photo-set").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('full-width')
    .find("img").attr("sizes", "(min-width: 29em) 100vw, 100vw")
  });
```

```css
  .bp2-col-1-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .full-width {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photo-set col-1-1 bp2-col-1-2">
    <img src="..." srcset="..."
      sizes="(min-width: 29em) 50vw, 100vw">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. This does exactly what I hoped it would do. The browser gets initially downloads only the necessary 50% width image, and then after click it fetches a larger image.  Thanks